# Minimum length for shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, building-regulations

The shower drain in my fiberglass shower is poking up and slightly off center, which caused a small leak.  I had assistance with fixing it, but it gives very little clearance below for me to drywall the ceiling back up.  I could shave the drywall down, but I also think the run from the trap to the main drain line is slightly off kilter which means eventually it may leak again.  So I'm going to fix it proper so there is no sheering force at all.

My question is this - is there a minimum length the 2" drain from the shower must be before it hits the trap?  I'm not touching anything after the trap except to connect my new drain/trap combo to it.

Because if there is no minimum (obviously you need a minimum to install the drain and couple the pieces together) I can definitely shave off like 1-1.5" of the drain line from the shower to the trap.

Comment: A picture would help. What size floor joists are in place?  Most likely the best option is going to be to fit the plumbing into the space you have rather than  modifying the space to accommodate the plumbing. Shaving sheetrock will result in unsatisfactory finish I.e. bulging cracking or a hole.

Comment: I agree about fitting the plumbing into the space vs changing the space.  I may not have worded my question correctly.  I'm not home at the moment but I suspect they are 2x10 going from memory.

I'm just going to use the least space possible I think.

Comment: If they are’2x10 there is no reason you can’t get a trap fitted in the space.  Have fun :)

Comment: They can't be 2x10, thne.  I honestly forgot to look last night.  Either way, I definitely can trim off some of the pvc from the trap to the shower.  Lots of unused space there.